# How to make an area transparent in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, path, pathfinder

In the image below you'll see the white section (highlighted blue). The black section behind it is one path, and the white another. How do I remove the white from the black so it becomes transparent? Hope that makes sense <3

[image: How do I remove the highlighted white section and make it transparent?]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By selecting both shapes and hitting <kbd>Subtract</kbd> on the `Pathfinder` Palette:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This answer addresses if the above has THREE shapes and not two.  Vincent's answer is correct if there are two shapes.

I would take your designs as so:

[image]

In this instance I would select ONLY the Polygons:

[image]

Navigate to `Object -> Compound Path -> Make` or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>:

[image]

If I select everything:

[image]

and do `Pathfinder` with an option of `Minus Front` on a design that has three shapes it will result in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend another way of creating the transparent areas: the 'Knockout Group Option'. It is extremely useful especially when working with text objects (but of course it works with any kind of shapes). Here is a short example:

- Create white rectangle (background) and put it into the separate
  layer:

[image]

- Create a new layer (e.g. text) and draw black rectangle:

[image]

- Put your text over the black rectangle (the same layer):

[image]

- Set Text Fill and Stroke Colors to None:

[image]

- Go to Appearance Panel > Add New Fill:

[image]

- Drag the new fill below the Characters:

[image]

- Click on the Opacity link (below the new fill) and set Opacity to 0%:

[image]

- Go back to your artboard, select the black rectangle and the text and group it (Object > Group)
- Go to Appearance Panel > Click on the Opacity link > and check the Knockout Group option:

[image]

- And here it is! The black rectangle has been punched with the text:

[image]

- Note that **this method doesn’t expand your text** – you can freely change the string content and Adobe Illustrator will recalculate your work fully automatically. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing that works for me is going to tools on the left and selecting live paint bucket and selecting "none" in the swatches then painting the space I need gone!