# Illustrator CS6: How to cut an area (shape without fill) out of another?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, transparency, pathfinder

Here's example picture below. How to make all the white areas transparent? Triangles, line and text. I have tried Pathfinder but I can't get it work correctly. Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Hi Marissa, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38794/how-to-make-an-area-transparent-in-illustrator?rq=1

Comment: @Scott that's what Darth said as well, but this one is different in that the shapes to be subtracted here are either type or strokes, not full shapes. The answers on the question you link to won't help this question, as the OP indicates she already used the Pathfinder.

Comment: Okay.. here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20648/making-parts-of-illustrator-logo-transparent-rather-than-faking-it-with-the-ba?rq=1 :) There are at least 2 others as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to *expand* all these white shapes before subtracting them from the black circle. Select each of them and choose <kbd>Object > Expand</kbd>. For the text, you can also choose <kbd>Type > Create Outlines</kbd> but that won't work for the regular shapes.

Then, subtract them from the black circle one by one. Be warned that you will have to ungroup the text after expanding. It might be convenient to turn the resulting shapes into a compound path (<kbd>Object > Compound Path > Make</kbd>) before subtracting. that way, you won't have to subtract every letter shape individually.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally I got it work. I selected all white shapes including text --> Expand --> Compound Path --> selected also black circle  and then used the Minus Front.

Comment: Welcome! If this answer helped you, please consider marking it the 'correct' one by clicking the grey checkmark below the answer score. Besides giving both you and me some reputation points, this is good for this site's stats and credibility. Thanks!